# A question on in-centres and ex-centres.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

$I$, $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ are the in-centres and ex-centres of $\triangle ABC$. If $I(0,0)$, $I_1(2,3)$, $I_2(5,7)$ then the distance between the orthocentres of $\triangle II_1I_3$ and $\triangle I_1I_2I_3$ is?

I tried using the in-centres and ex-centres formulae but again ended up with complications. Can anyone please help me out with a simple solution? Also, since the origin is in-centre, can we tell it's an equilateral triangle?

P.S.- it's my first question using MathJax so don't downvote my question for any mistakes

Comment: As $|II_1|\ne|II_2|$ we can tell that it's **not** an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an important property of the incenter and the three excenters of a triangle, that these four points form a so-called orthocentric system (see, for example, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle) and then [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_system)). I quote: "If four points form an orthocentric system, then each of the four points is the orthocenter of the other three."
 Therefore, the orthocenter of $\bigtriangleup II_1I_3$ is $I_2$ and the orthocenter of $\bigtriangleup I_1I_2I_3$ is $I$. The requested distance between the two orthocenters is then $I_2I=\sqrt{(5-0)^2+(7-0)^2}=\sqrt{74}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just $II_2=\sqrt{5^2+7^2}=\sqrt{74}$.

Comment: How? On what basis? Can you please write an elaborate solution with a figure?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar Because a sum of supplementary adjacent angles equal to $180^{\circ}$ and from here the bisectors  of   supplementary adjacent angles are perpendiculars.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. Please write a complete answer as I am only a beginner. Please.